# Proving that $AB\neq 0$ if $\operatorname{rank} A =2, \operatorname{rank} B=3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A_{2\times4}, B_{4\times4}$ such that $\operatorname{rank}A =2$, $\operatorname{rank} B=3$. Prove that $AB\neq 0$.

We know that rank $(AB) \le \min\{\operatorname{rank}A, \operatorname{rank}B\}=2$ so we only need to show that $\operatorname{rank}(AB)\geq 1$.

I suppose that multiplying two row reduced matrices with parameters to have corresponding row and column spaces wouldn't be general. So any hints on how to continue?

Comment: Extended Sylvester inequality: $r(A)+r(B)-n\le r(AB)\le min\{r(A),r(B)\}$, for $n=4$ gives $1\le r(AB)\le 2$.

Comment: why is it important that you can bound rank$(AB)$ from above in this question?

Comment: That's about the only inequality I knew with regard to rank, so I tried to use it. @OfirSchnabel

Comment: OK, for me sometimes less is more, and this is one of this cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of $AB$ as an opartor from $\mathbb{F}^4$ to $\mathbb{F}^2$.

Since rank$(B)=3$, dim$($Im $(B))=3$.

Now since dim$($ker$(A))=2$, there exist a vector in $v\in Im(B)$ such that
$Av\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\text{rank}(A) + \text{rank}(B) - n \leq \text{rank}(AB)
$$

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$ in general.

In this case $n = 4$, so $\text{rank}(AB) \geq 1$ Therefore $AB \neq 0$.

EDIT: top inequality is known as Sylvester's Inequality. Source: The Matrix Cookbook.

Answer (score 1):

Since the rank of $A$ is $2$, its two rows $a_1$, $a_2$ are l.i., and since the rank of $B$ is $3$, it has three l.i. columns, $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$.

If $AB$ were $0$, then the subspaces of $\Bbb R^4$ (or whatever escalar field is)
$$U=\langle a_1,a_2\rangle$$
$$V=\langle b_1,b_2,b_3\rangle$$
would be orthogonal, but $\dim U+\dim V=5$. This is impossible.